# Wrapping big list in Python 2.7 to make it immutable

Tags: python, list, wrapper, immutability

In case I have a really big `list` (>100k elements) that can be retrieved from some object through function call, is there a way to wrap that list to make it immutable to the caller without copying it to `tuple`?

In the following example I have only one `list` field, but the solution should work for any number of `list` fields.

```
class NumieHolder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._numies = []

    def add(self, new_numie):
        self._numies.append(new_numie)

    @property
    def numies(self):
        # return numies embedded in immutable wrapper/view
        return ??? numies ???

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nh = NumieHolder()

    for numie in xrange(100001): # >100k holds
        nh.add(numie)

    # messing with numies should result in exception
    nh.numies[3] = 4

    # but I still want to use index operator
    print '100th numie:', nh.numies[99]
```

I would know how to write adapter that behaves that way, but I'm interested if there is already some standard solution (i.e. in standard library or widely known library) I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such wrapper in the standard library (or other prominent libraries). The main reason is that `list` is supposed to be a *mutable* sequence type with index access. The *immutable* sequence type would be a `tuple` as you already said yourself. So usually, the standard approach to make a list immutable would be to make it into a tuple by calling `tuple(lst)`.

This is obviously not what you want, as you want to avoid to copy all the elements. So instead, you can create a custom type that wraps the list, and offers all non-modifying methods `list` also supports:

```
class ImmutableList:
    def __init__ (self, actualList):
        self.__lst = actualList
    def __len__ (self):
        return self.__lst.__len__()
    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        return self.__lst.__getitem__(key)
    def __iter__ (self):
        return self.__lst.__iter__()
    def __reversed__ (self):
        return self.__lst.__reversed__()
    def __contains__ (self, item):
        return self.__lst.__contains__(item)
    def __repr__ (self):
        return self.__lst.__repr__()
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.__lst.__str__()
```

```
>>> original = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> immutable = ImmutableList(original)
>>> immutable
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> immutable[2]
3
>>> for i in immutable:
        print(i, end='; ')

1; 2; 3; 4; 
>>> list(reversed(immutable))
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> immutable[1] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    immutable[1] = 4
TypeError: 'ImmutableList' object does not support item assignment
```

The alternative would be to subtype `list` and override `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` to raise an exception instead, but I would suggest against that, as a subtype of `list` would be expected to have the same interface as `list` itself. `ImmutableList` above on the other hand is just some indexable sequence type which happens to wrap a real list itself. Apart from that, having it as a subtype of `list` would actually require you to copy the contents once, so wrapping is definitely better if you don’t want to recreate all those items (which seems to be your point—otherwise you could just use `tuple`).

Comment: So it means there is no such a class in the standard library or some  widely known package not in the standard library?

Comment: Why not define `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` to raise exception as said, and then proxy to the `self.__lst` - that way you expose the full set of the wrapped object's api instead of listing the delegations...

Comment: No, `tuple` is the standard indexable and immutable sequence type. `list` is meant to be mutable. The usual solution would be to create a tuple from your list, but as you want to avoid copying the items, you don’t really have a different choice.

Comment: For such a wrapper not to be in the std lib is acceptable answer. Can you please just add that conclusion at the top of your answer?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that. Jon’s idea was actually to use `__getattr__` to delegate to `list`’s original special methods, but that doesn’t work as special methods are not looked up with `__getattr__` (or `__getattribute__`) but over the type directly, so you can’t automatically delegate special methods.

Comment: That last sentence seems to be not true.  One does not have to make any copies when subclassing `list`.  One can still forward calls to a member reference.  Furthermore, you forgot to implement slices.

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev Since you cannot overwrite literal behavior in Python, in order to create a subtyped list from a literal, you _are_ copying a list to your list subtype. If you just wrap it, you can reuse the list instance.

Answer (score 2):

See [Emulating Container Types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for the "special" methods you'd want to implement or override. Namely, you'd want to implement `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` methods to raise an exception, so the list cannot be modified.