# In python, how does one make an input parameter to function immutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, constants, immutability

Suppose we have a function:

```
import copy

def demo_function(list_in)
    list_out = copy.deepcopy(list_in)
    list_in.append("howdy")
    return list_out
```

Notice that we append to `list_in` instead of `list_out`. However, `demo_function` is not actually supposed to modify its input. We want to enforce this. An error should be thrown if someone accidentally modifies `list_in` somewhere inside the body of `demo_function` How can we implement this type of error checking?

The following is my best attempt, but it doesn't work. The string "howdy" still ends up getting appended to `list_in`; no error is thrown

```
class Frozen(object): 
    # The Frozen class was developed by ActiveState Software Inc.
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '_value': return super(Frozen, self).__getattribute__(name)
        v = getattr(self._value, name)
        return v if hasattr(v, '__hash__') else Frozen(v)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_value': super(Frozen, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else: raise Exception("Can't modify frozen object {0}".format(self._value))

def const(some_function):    
    def wrapper(fargs,*args,**kwargs):
        for f in fargs:
            f = Frozen(f)
            pass
        for a in args:
            a = Frozen(a)
            pass
        for k in kwargs:
            k = Frozen(k)
            pass
        some_function(fargs, *args, **kwargs)    
    return wrapper

@const
def demo_function(list_in):
    list_out = copy.deepcopy(list_in)
    list_in.append("howdy")
    return list_out

lisandra = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

modified_lisandra = demo_function(lisandra) 

print(lisandra)
```

## Edit:

I regret using a list as my example. I really want a general solution that would make a function's inputs immutable (const) no matter what their datatypes are. It is very easy to convert a python list into a tuple. However, what if the input to the function is an instance of some user-defined class? You do not know how to convert it into a tuple. Even if you do know how to convert the object into a tuple, you do not want to write a different solution for each and every datatype in your project. We want a single solution that will freeze the values of a function's inputs, no matter the datatype of those inputs.

Comment: Use a tuple?  `lisandra = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: You might want to use a tuple instead.

Comment: Why do you want it to be immutable? What are you hoping to gain?

Comment: Why would anybody *else* be doing anything inside semo_function? And if they are couldn't they just circumvent your protection?

Comment: Of possible interest: [Wrapping big list in Python 2.7 to make it immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000994/wrapping-big-list-in-python-2-7-to-make-it-immutable#21001628)

Comment: @AlexTaylor asked, "Why do you want it to be immutable? What are you hoping to gain?" My answer is that we want to prevent accidental modifications of function inputs. For this purpose, many languages in the C-family support a `const` keyword. If you try to modify a `const` object, you will get an error. Copying an object (pass by value), will prevent you from modifying the original, but is very inefficient. It makes more sense to pass by reference. With references there is a danger that we modify the original object. Sometimes we only want read-only capability, not read-write.

Comment: Well in that case, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292194/4822566

Answer (score 0):

You could always try something like this ..

```
import copy

def demo_function(list_in):
    original = list_in[:]
    list_out = copy.deepcopy(list_in)
    list_in.append("howdy")
    assert original == list_in
    return list_out
```